# Which do you recommend for learning how to write proofs -- How to Prove it by Velleman, or Book of Proof?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, reference-request, solution-verification, proof-writing

Which of the two books do you recommend? I have been studying mathematics for three semesters and would like to improve my skills in demonstrating and understanding proofs more easily.

I am open to other book suggestions.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven’t read these or any books specifically tailored to proof-writing, but I will say one of the best passive ways to learn to write proofs is to read proofs.  (The same applies, by the way, for most other types of writing as well.) Make sure you can read and follow every proof in whichever texts you are reading on whichever subject, and your brain will start to passively pick up on what does and does not need to be said.

Comment: Users unfamiliar with Book Of Proof (such as myself, until a few minutes ago) can start at https://www.people.vcu.edu/~rhammack/BookOfProof/

Comment: Once you get past the calculus sequence you will take courses where you are required to prove theorems rather than compute results. At that point you will get plenty of practice and your ability to both read and write proofs will improve. This also assumes you will be taking courses in the math department. If you take the calculus sequence and then move into an engineering or science discipline, then that may not be the case.